# How to run Mono on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wine, mono

I have installed mono from Terminal.

[image]

How am I going to run it?

Comment: When ever possible do not show pictures of text include the text in the question.

Comment: It really depends on whatever you are trying to achieve. Your attached output literally tells you `Usage is: mono [options] program [program-options]` and an option list. Please edit your question and tell us exactly what you are trying to implement.

Comment: You might also want to refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the folder where you saved your executable `file.exe`, right click > Open terminal here, then type the following in the terminal:

```bsh
mono file.exe
```

If you need you can type `mono --help` for other options